# Moving from Linear Probing to Quadratic Probing (hash collisons)

Tags: c, hashtable, hash-collision, quadratic-probing

My current implementation of an Hash Table is using Linear Probing and now I want to move to Quadratic Probing (and later to chaining and maybe double hashing too). I've read a few articles, tutorials, wikipedia, etc... But I still don't know exactly what I should do.

Linear Probing, basically, has a step of 1 and that's easy to do. When searching, inserting or removing an element from the Hash Table, I need to calculate an hash and for that I do this:

```
index = hash_function(key) % table_size;
```

Then, while searching, inserting or removing I loop through the table until I find a free bucket, like this:

```
do {
    if(/* CHECK IF IT'S THE ELEMENT WE WANT */) {
        // FOUND ELEMENT

        return;
    } else {
        index = (index + 1) % table_size;
    }
while(/* LOOP UNTIL IT'S NECESSARY */);
```

As for Quadratic Probing, I think what I need to do is change how the "index" step size is calculated but that's what I don't understand how I should do it. I've seen various pieces of code, and all of them are somewhat different.

Also, I've seen some implementations of Quadratic Probing where the hash function is changed to accommodated that (but not all of them). Is that change really needed or can I avoid modifying the hash function and still use Quadratic Probing?

**EDIT:**
After reading everything pointed out by Eli Bendersky below I think I got the general idea. Here's part of the code at http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx:

```
15   for ( step = 1; table->table[h] != EMPTY; step++ ) {
16     if ( compare ( key, table->table[h] ) == 0 )
17       return 1;
18 
19     /* Move forward by quadratically, wrap if necessary */
20     h = ( h + ( step * step - step ) / 2 ) % table->size;
21   }
```

There's 2 things I don't get... They say that quadratic probing is usually done using `c(i)=i^2`. However, in the code above, it's doing something more like `c(i)=(i^2-i)/2`

I was ready to implement this on my code but I would simply do:

```
index = (index + (index^index)) % table_size;
```

...and not:

```
index = (index + (index^index - index)/2) % table_size;
```

If anything, I would do:

```
index = (index + (index^index)/2) % table_size;
```

...cause I've seen other code examples diving by two. Although I don't understand why...

**1)** Why is it subtracting the step?
**2)** Why is it diving it by 2?

Comment: keep in mind that quadratic probing is only effective if the table size is prime and the load factor is < 0.5; see http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx for an overview on different collision resolution strategies

Comment: @Cristoph: that statement isn't quite right.  If the table size is prime, then it is guaranteed to work right if the load factor is < 0.5; but it's not true that this is the *only* case where quadratic probing works.  For example, it can also be effective with a power-of-2 table size and an arbitrary load factor (see my answer).

Comment: @Mathew: there's a difference between 'work' and 'work effectively'; if the load factor is too high, (secondary) clustering might become an issue again

Comment: @Cristoph: sure ("arbitrary load factor" was probably a poor choice of words on my part; a load factor of 0.999 won't be a good idea regardless of fancy probing).  But 0.75 is a reasonable load factor for a hash table to work fairly well even with linear probing (as long as the hash function is good), and will indeed work effectively with quadratic probing and a power-of-2 table size (probing visits all buckets, like linear probing, but primary clustering is reduced) - so the statement "quadratic probing is only effective if the table size is prime and the load factor is < 0.5" is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to modify the hash function for quadratic probing. The simplest form of quadratic probing is really just adding consequent squares to the calculated position instead of linear 1, 2, 3.

There's a good resource [here](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page241.html). The following is taken from there. This is the simplest form of quadratic probing when the simple polynomial `c(i) = i^2` is used:

[image]

In the more general case the formula is:

[image]

And you can pick your constants.

Keep, in mind, however, that quadratic probing is useful only in certain cases. As the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing) states:

> Quadratic probing provides good memory
>   caching because it preserves some
>   locality of reference; however, linear
>   probing has greater locality and,
>   thus, better cache performance.
>   Quadratic probing better avoids the
>   clustering problem that can occur with
>   linear probing, although it is not
>   immune.

---

**EDIT:** Like many things in computer science, the exact constants and polynomials of quadratic probing are heuristic. Yes, the simplest form is `i^2`, but you may choose any other polynomial. Wikipedia gives the example with `h(k,i) = (h(k) + i + i^2)(mod m)`.

Therefore, it is difficult to answer your "why" question. The only "why" here is why do you need quadratic probing at all? Having problems with other forms of probing and getting a clustered table? Or is it just a homework assignment, or self-learning?

Keep in mind that by far the most common collision resolution technique for hash tables is either chaining or linear probing. Quadratic probing is a heuristic option available for special cases, and unless you know what you're doing very well, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Sorry but math formulas doesn't help me. :( And you didn't give me more than what I've already read about it.

Comment: @Nazgulled: I really don't see what you're having trouble with - and as you got no other answers, maybe I'm not the only one. I think you should try to elaborate your question and rephrase it to explain exactly what you need

Comment: I look at the math formulas and I don't understand them and I also don't know what to do in code. I need to know what to do in words, not math formulas.

Comment: @Nazgulled: I've added to my answer. I hope you realize that in order to program successfully, you *must* have an understanding of formulas, or at least the will to look at them

Comment: This is for self-learning porpuses. I'll have a project where I'll have to use hash tables (probably) but for that I'll use chaining, I just want to learn the different ways to do it so I can write about them in the final report and argue why I picked one versus the other.
For Linear probing I stopped looking when I visited every bucket on the hash table, but for quadratic probing, when should I stop looking?

Comment: @Nazgulled: the page I linked to has a discussion - as long as the size of the table is prime, the first M/2 (M is the size) samples are unique. Read up about it there, or any other online resource on algorithms

Answer (score 11):

There is a particularly simple and elegant way to implement quadratic probing if your table size is a power of 2:

```
step = 1;

do {
    if(/* CHECK IF IT'S THE ELEMENT WE WANT */) {
        // FOUND ELEMENT

        return;
    } else {
        index = (index + step) % table_size;
        step++;
    }
} while(/* LOOP UNTIL IT'S NECESSARY */);
```

Instead of looking at offsets 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... from the original index, this will look at offsets 0, 1, 3, 6, 10... (the i<sup>th</sup> probe is at offset (i*(i+1))/2, i.e. it's quadratic).

This is guaranteed to hit every position in the hash table (so you are guaranteed to find an empty bucket if there is one) *provided* the table size is a power of 2.

---

Here is a sketch of a proof:

1. Given a table size of n, we want to show that we will get n distinct values of (i*(i+1))/2 (mod n)  with i = 0 ... n-1.
2. We can prove this by contradiction.  Assume that there are fewer than n distinct values: if so, there must be at least two distinct integer values for i in the range [0, n-1] such that (i*(i+1))/2 (mod n) is the same.  Call these p and q, where p < q.
3. i.e. (p * (p+1)) / 2 = (q * (q+1)) / 2 (mod n)
4. => (p<sup>2</sup> + p) / 2 = (q<sup>2</sup> + q) / 2 (mod n)
5. => p<sup>2</sup> + p = q<sup>2</sup> + q (mod 2n)
6. => q<sup>2</sup> - p<sup>2</sup> + q - p = 0 (mod 2n)
7. Factorise => (q - p) (p + q + 1) = 0 (mod 2n)
8. (q - p) = 0 is the trivial case p = q.
9. (p + q + 1) = 0 (mod 2n) is impossible: our values of p and q are in the range [0, n-1], and q > p, so (p + q + 1) must be in the range [2, 2n-2].
10. As we are working modulo 2n, we must also deal with the tricky case where both factors are non-zero, but multiply to give 0 (mod 2n):

    - Observe that the difference between the two factors (q - p) and (p + q + 1) is (2p + 1), which is an odd number - so one of the factors must be even, and the other must be odd.
    - (q - p) (p + q + 1) = 0 (mod 2n) => (q - p) (p + q + 1) is divisible by 2n.  **If n (and hence 2n) is a power of 2**, this requires the even factor to be a multiple of 2n (because all of the prime factors of 2n are 2, whereas none of the prime factors of our odd factor are).
    - But (q - p) has a maximum value of n-1, and (p + q + 1) has a maximum value of 2n-2 (as seen in step 9), so neither can be a multiple of 2n.
    - So this case is impossible as well.
11. Therefore the assumption that there are fewer than n distinct values (in step 2) must be false.

(If the table size is *not* a power of 2, this falls apart at step 10.)