# Proof the quadratic probing function

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, probing, quadratic-probing

I would really appreciate if someone could help solve this problem. The question is:
Consider the following hash function: h(k, i) = (h’(k) + (1/2) (i + i^2 )) mod m, where m = 2^p for some positive integer p. Prove or disprove that for any k, the probe sequence is a permutation of <0, 1, 2, ...,m – 1>

Comment: What does h'(k) denote?

Comment: its is a hash function

Comment: the initial hash function, which remains constant throughout, something like (k mod 11)

Comment: "Please do my homework for me" is a poor question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is a "probe sequence"?

Comment: <h(k, 0), h(k, 1), ..., h(k, m – 1)>

Comment: this is a probe sequence

Comment: This has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348187/moving-from-linear-probing-to-quadratic-probing-hash-collisons/2349774#2349774).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Let's assume that `h(k, i) = h(k, j)`. 
Then `h'(k) + 1/2 * i * (i + 1) = h'(k) + 1/2 * j * (j + 1) (mod m)` <=> 
 `1/2 * i * (i + 1) = 1/2 * j * (j + 1) (mod m)` => 
`i * (i + 1) = j * (j + 1) (mod 2m)` <=> `i * i - j * j + i - j = 0 (mod 2m)` <=> 
`(i - j) * (i + j + 1) = 0 (mod 2m)`. The second term is odd and `2m = 2^(p + 1)`, thus 
`i = j (mod 2m)` => `i = j (mod m)`.

Comment: Thank you! Solves the problem nicely!